# Xcode Simulators vanish upon upgrade to new version

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I know many of us are facing this issue. But I can't seem to find any definitive answers to this problem.

Why does Xcode delete old simulators when it is upgraded?

I mean, adding a new one is fine, why delete the old ones which we'll have to download all over again?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does not delete old simulators when it is upgraded.

Run `xcrun simctl list` and you should still see them, likely listed as unavailable because the old runtime is no longer available.

Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and download the older runtime version(s) that you want.

Comment: Thanks. But having to download it all over again is a pain. Especially for older versions.

Comment: You don't need to download it again.  Xcode does not delete them.  Once you've installed it to /Library/Developer, it will stay there for future versions of Xcode to use as well.